# Query que muestre datos dentro de un rango de fechas

Tags: php, sql, datepicker

Quiero mostrar los datos en un `PDF` dentro de un rango de fecha seleccionada a partir de `datepicker`, el `PDF` se genera y muestra los encabezados de las columnas pero no la información, lo mas seguro es que sea el `query` que estoy haciendo.

Los datos que se deberán mostrar tiene que ver con la fecha de registro.
Es decir si elijo `2018-12-05 a 2018-12-12`, me mostrara los `item` entre ese rango

Query:

```
if(isset($_GET['fecha1']) && isset($_GET['fecha2']))
    {

      $fecha1 = $_GET["fecha1"];
      $fecha2 = $_GET["fecha2"];

      //Trae todos los item que esten por debajo de su minimo en stock.
      $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
      $query = "SELECT i.description_item,i.quantity,u.name_unit,i.reorder_Level,
      i.target_Stock,l.name_location,i.commentt,io.quantity_s,io.registerTicket
      FROM inventory_list AS i
      INNER JOIN unit_mesurement AS u ON id_unit = fkUnit
      INNER JOIN location AS l on id_location = fkLocation
      INNER JOIN inventory_output as io on id_output = fkInventory
      WHERE '".$fecha1."' AND '".$fecha2."'";
      $result = $connection->executeQuery($query,array($fecha1,$fecha2));
      if ($result > 0) {...}
```

El campo de la fecha de registro es `io.registerDate` de `Inventory_output`

Cuando se da click en generar reporte el onclick manda a esta function en el js:

```
function Report(fecha1,fecha2)
{
        var fecha1 =document.getElementById("start").value;
        var fecha2 =document.getElementById("end").value;

        setTimeout(function(){ window.open("http://localhost/WareHouse/datereport.php?fecha1="+fecha1+"&fecha2="+fecha2, "_blank"); }, 1000);
        initArticles(); $('#myModalReport').modal('hide');
        console.log(fecha1);
        console.log(fecha2);
}
```

Como le pudiera hacer, para que funcione correctamente de acuerdo a la fecha?

Comment: No estas comparando la fecha con ningun campo de tu tabla.

Comment: como dijo @alanfcm no estas filtrando registros en un rango de fechas, para hacer ello debes tener, me imagino yo, un campo donde registres un fecha y para filtrar por un rango debes poner en tu consulta: `WHERE "campo_fecha" BETWEEN $fecha1 AND $fecha2`

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo el uso del operador de comparación BETWEEN, el cual compara entre un valor mínimo y un máximo. Tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT 
  i.description_item,
  i.quantity,
  u.name_unit,
  i.reorder_Level,
  i.target_Stock,
  l.name_location,
  i.commentt,
  io.quantity_s,
  io.registerTicket
FROM inventory_list AS i
  INNER JOIN unit_mesurement AS u ON id_unit = fkUnit
  INNER JOIN location AS l on id_location = fkLocation
  INNER JOIN inventory_output as io on id_output = fkInventory
  WHERE io.registerDate BETWEEN '".$fecha1."' AND '".$fecha2."'"
```

Por otro lado, te recomiendo ampliamente que no involucres variables directo con tu consulta (no concatenes) debido a que esto presenta un alto riesgo de vulnerabilidad.

**¿Qué te pronpongo?** Utiliza PDO para conectarte a tu motor preferido y aprovecha funciones como [PDOStatement::bindValue(...)](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) para proteger tu sistema contra inyecciones SQL.

Más información sobre el operador BETWEEN:

- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).
- [MaríaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/between-and/).

Answer (score 1):

puedes colocar todos los datos de la tabla? estas comparando con dos campos, deberias colocar algo así

```
$query = "SELECT i.description_item,i.quantity,u.name_unit,i.reorder_Level,
  i.target_Stock,l.name_location,i.commentt,io.quantity_s,io.registerTicket
  FROM inventory_list AS i
  INNER JOIN unit_mesurement AS u ON id_unit = fkUnit
  INNER JOIN location AS l on id_location = fkLocation
  INNER JOIN inventory_output as io on id_output = fkInventory
  WHERE io.registerDate >= '".$fecha1."' AND  io.registerDate <= '".$fecha2."'";
```

Comment: Donde pones campo1 y 2 te refieres a que debería de ir registerDate?

Comment: si, es correcto alli debes comparar tu campo de fecha, una recomendación es imprimor la variable $query y probarla en el SQl así ves si la consulta está bien escrita y te funciona, creo que se les dice usar banderas.

Comment: Tengo solo dos fechas como prueba 2018-05-12 y 2018-12-12, la primera vez que selecciono este rango de fechas en el datepicker, me arroja exactamente los 2 resultados, si recargo la pagina y selecciono de 2018-11-12 a 2018-12-12 fecha actual, lo correcto seria que me mostrara solo uno, pero no es así, no muestra nada,podrías orientarme en esto?

Comment: utiliza la función BETWEEN como te comentaron abajo, esa también funciona bien. tambien puedes ejecutar la consulta en tu sql para probar los resultados directamente y luego lo adaptas al php

Comment: Ocurre los mismo si pongo el BETWEEN,puede que tenga que ver con que, el formato que se elige desde el datepicker sea dd-mm-aaaa y cuando se genera el  PDF en la url que se muestra abajo sea aaaa-mm-dd?

Comment: Prueba imprimir la consulta tipo, echo $query; eso lo pegas en tu sql builder y alli ves si funciona, otra que puedes hacer es formatear tus valores y ponerlos formato aaaa-mm-dd